# Date type in where clause with case syntax

Tags: sql

```
SELECT *
  FROM orders do
 WHERE (CASE TO_CHAR(sysdate,'D')
        WHEN '1'    THEN do.create_date=sysdate
        WHEN '2'    THEN do.create_date BETWEEN sysdate-1 AND sysdate
        WHEN '3'    THEN do.create_date BETWEEN sysdate-2 AND sysdate
        WHEN '4'    THEN do.create_date BETWEEN sysdate-3 AND sysdate
        WHEN '5'    THEN do.create_date BETWEEN sysdate-4 AND sysdate
        WHEN '6'    THEN do.create_date BETWEEN sysdate-5 AND sysdate
        WHEN '7'    THEN do.create_date BETWEEN sysdate-6 AND sysdate
        END)
```

What is wrong in this? I am getting the below error message

```
Error Msg : 
ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 46 Column: 37
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. Note that your error message mentions line 46, but your SQL doesn't stretch to line 46. When that happens, you should identify which is line 46.  Also, in general, when you ask an SQL question, it is worth specifying which DBMS you're using — there are many differences between the different DBMS (even when the question is about basic SQL). Finally (and this is not a trap you fell into), please remember to give your tables names — it is surprising how often the question is 'I have this (_anonymous_) table with the following schema'.

Answer (score 1):

The `where` statement returns a value, not a boolean.  That is, the `between` doesn't make sense in the `when` clause.

Here is an alternative way of expressing the condition:

```
select *
from orders do
where do.created_date between sysdate - (cast(to_char(sysdate,'D') as int) - 1) and sysdate;
```

If you wanted to do this with `between`, it would be something like this:

```
select *
from orders do
where do.create_date between s
          (case to_char(sysdate,'D')
               WHEN '1'    THEN sysdate
               WHEN '2'    THEN sysdate-1
               WHEN '3'    THEN sysdate-2 
               WHEN '4'    THEN sysdate-3
               WHEN '5'    THEN sysdate-4
               WHEN '6'    THEN sysdate-5
               WHEN '7'    THEN sysdate-6
           END) and sysdate;
```

Comment: I think you need `(CAST(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'D') AS INT) - 1)` to avoid an off-by-one error...otherwise, a lot more compact.